# Centos 7x64 - Deploy Rails using Nginx and Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, node.js, nginx

I've followed this tutorial [How to deploy rails apps using unicorn and nginx on CentOS 6.5](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5) to deploy in Centos 7x64.

The first time I made it work accessing to `http://[my-ip]:8080/tasks`, but now after repeating the exercise many times I only see a 'can not access' in the browser. But I can see Nginx start page in `http://[my-ip]`.

[image: Browser here]

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Are these settings okay considering I want to store multiple Rails apps in same Droplet?
3. In other Nginx tutorials, inside nginx folder I've seen a folder called 'sites-enabled', but in my config it isn't. How is that important?

#### These are my CentOS settings:

> General settings

```
echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
yum -y update
yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
yum repolist
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" list available
yum --enablerepo=epel info htop
yum --enablerepo=epel install -y htop  
yum install -y curl-devel nano sqlite-devel libyaml-devel
```

> Install Ruby and RoR

```
sudo yum install -y ruby
sudo yum install -y gcc g++ make automake autoconf curl-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel sqlite-devel
sudo yum install -y ruby-rdoc ruby-devel
sudo yum install -y rubygems
sudo gem update
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

> Install Unicorn

```
gem install unicorn
```

> Install Nginx

```
sudo yum install -y nginx
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

> Install NodeJS

```
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ 
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36.tar.gz  
tar xzvf node-v* && cd node-v*   
./configure  
make  
sudo make install  
node --version
```

#### Generate Rails app

```
# Create a sample Rails application
cd  /var
mkdir www
cd www
rails new my_app

# Enter the application directory
cd my_app

# Create a sample resource
rails generate scaffold Task title:string note:text

# Create a sample database
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production  rake db:migrate

# Create a directory to hold the PID files
mkdir pids
```

#### These are my configuration files:

> my_app/config/unicorn.rb

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/var/www/my_app"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/var/www/my_app/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {


    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /root/my_app/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

#### Run inside the my_app

```
unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

#### Start nginx

```
systemctl start nginx.service
systemctl status nginx.service 



nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-01-29 13:37:08 EST; 1min 57s ago
  Process: 642 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 604 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 650 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─650 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
           └─654 nginx: worker process

demo nginx[604]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
demo nginx[604]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
demo systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
demo systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
demo systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

#### Logs

> log/unicorn.log

```
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.886225 #11502]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn.[app name].sock fd=10
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.886616 #11502]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fd=11
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.886891 #11502]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.887657 #11502]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.888673 #11505]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=11505
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.889029 #11505]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.891061 #11502]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.918331 #11508]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=11508
I, [2015-01-29T14:45:58.918732 #11508]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-01-29T14:46:03.608903 #11508]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2015-01-29T14:46:03.609694 #11505]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

> config/production.log

```
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.225698 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (3.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL)
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.226055 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.229402 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (2.8ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.230780 #1864] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.234599 #1864]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateTasks (20150129032219)
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.235363 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.237769 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  CREATE TABLE "tasks" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar, "note" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.245241 #1864] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES (?)  [["version", "20150129032219"]]
D, [2015-01-28T22:22:34.248567 #1864] DEBUG -- :    (3.0ms)  commit transaction
```

> /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
Empty
```

#### Start Rails log

```
[root@demo my_app]# rails s
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-29 14:59:12] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-29 14:59:12] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-01-29 14:59:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11560 port=3000
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, I suggest you to install Ruby with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) even when this has nothing to do with your problem.
- The next thing I notice is, that you get an error when you start nginx: `Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument`. Maybe your config doesn't gets loaded?
- Please also check the nginx, Rails and Unicorn logs for further information. I think you will find a more useful problem description there. Your Unicorn log file is under `"/var/www/my_app/log/unicorn.log"`regarding to your config and the Rails log file is `"/var/www/my_app/log/production.log"`. The log file of nginx is somewhere under `"/var/log/nginx/"`, but I am not sure about that.

Please share your log files with us when you haven't find the problem then.

Regarding to your questions:

1. See above.
2. I don't know what a Droplet is, but you can run multiple Rails apps at once. Just create additional nginx hosts.
3. No it's not essential (see this [question + answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/527630/what-is-the-different-usages-for-sites-available-vs-the-conf-d-directory-for-ngi)). It is more a best practice for managing several virtual hosts. You can also cram all your hosts into the `default.conf` file.

Comment: At the end of the initial post I've added the logs, I guess it has something to do with unicorn. Droplet is the way Digital Ocean calls their virtual servers.

Comment: Ok. Nothing to find in the logs. Can you share a screenshot what you see when you try to access `http://[my-ip]:8080/tasks`? Maybe also try to restart the nginx server:
`/etc/init.d/nginx stop`
`/etc/init.d/nginx start`

Comment: Sure, here is the screenshot of what I see when I access with [ip], and what I see when I access [ip]:8080 http://s13.postimg.org/ext7q72bb/centos_nginx.jpg
I already tried start, stop, restart.

Comment: The first time I tried I could access application from [ip]:8080/tasks,  then I reseted virtual server to practice again, but now it doesn't work. I'm not sure if I did something different the first time.

Comment: You nginx server listens on port `80`, but you are trying to access your page on port `8080`. Try `http://[Your droplet's IP addr]/tasks` without `:8080` or change this line `listen 80` in `default.conf` to `listen 8080`.

Answer (score 1):

In dir rails:

```
 rm -rf public/assets
 rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=development
```

At the end, please apply the below permissions

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /www/[APLICACCION]/
```